# combine multiple column ,only return one value only with sum added for the value in year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[df variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aRph.png)

HI Im new to programming dataframe in pandas. I encountered this problem where Im stuck trying to figure out  how to join the country accordingly. Eg. in the dataset, I got 100+-  column of '**Argentina**' name and I wanted to produce only one column of Argentina with all value from the ***year*** of that country added .

df2 = { 'F2009': 'sum', 'F2010': 'sum'}

df3 = df.groupby(df['Country']).aggregate(df2)

I try a bit using aggregate for only 2 years.It not complete since the year have like 10 years of dataset.
Need help with the code or anyy better code for this.

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering the columns to aggregate based on their name (F followed by digit), then performing a `groupby.sum`:

```
df.filter(regex='F\d+').groupby(df['Country']).sum()
```

Comment: wow it worked. Thanks you SIR . This is first time see regex. It seems  that are so many things I dont know about